# How to pipe plotly line plot to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-express

How can we use `.pipe()` to get plotly express line plot?

## Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'count':np.random.randint(1,20,10)},
                  index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-10')
                 )
```

## Line plot (this works)

```
df1 = df.resample('2D').sum()
px.line(df1,x=df1.index,y='count')
```

## Using pipe

Here creating df1 is un-necessary. How can we use pipe?

My attempt

```
df.resample('2D').sum().pipe(px.line,x=lambda x: x.index,y='count')
# this does not work, gives empty plot
```

How to get the correct image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'count':np.random.randint(1,20,10)},
                  index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-10')
                 )

# line plot with pipe
df.resample('2D').sum().pipe(lambda ts:
                             px.line(ts, x=ts.index,y='count'))
```

Output:
[image]